# An error near FROM with DISTINCT in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_visitor_id varchar(5) NOT NULL, 
    the_visitor_visit timestamp NOT NULL,
    the_visitor_returning varchar(3)
);

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('VIS01', '2019-05-02 09:00:00','YES' ), 
       ('VIS01', '2019-05-04 12:00:00',NULL ), 
       ('VIS01', '2019-05-05 18:00:00',NULL ), 
       ('VIS02', '2019-05-06 18:30:00',NULL), 
       ('VIS02', '2019-05-15 12:00:00',NULL), 
       ('VIS03', '2019-06-30 18:00:00','YES');
```

And I want to get the first row for each `the_visitor_id` but I try this without success:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (the_visitor_id) 
FROM my_table 
WHERE the_visitor_returning IS NULL 
ORDER BY the_visitor_id, the_visitor_visit;
```

I receive this message error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM" LINE 2: FROM my_table`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select at least one column. But you probably want both ORDER BY columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (the_visitor_id) the_visitor_id, the_visitor_visit
FROM my_table 
WHERE the_visitor_returning IS NULL 
ORDER BY the_visitor_id, the_visitor_visit;
```

Comment: Thank you @jarlh, how silly I was, I missed to put a column, as you mention at least one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function to make a rank number for each visit by visitor, then filter where rank = 1 (the first visit for that visitor).

```
SELECT the_visitor_id, the_visitor_visit, the_visitor_returning FROM
(SELECT *, rank() over (partition by the_visitor_id order by the_visitor_visit) rnk
FROM my_table 
WHERE the_visitor_returning IS NULL) ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thank you @Greg Finley for your time and answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just wondering if you really want to filter by the returning column.  If you want all visitors, then it will filter out `3`.  This keeps all visitors:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (the_visitor_id) t.*
FROM my_table t
ORDER BY the_visitor_id,
      (the_visitor_returning IS NULL)::int DESC,
      the_visitor_visit;
```

`NULL` values are preferred, but if there are none, then you still have the earliest row for the visitor.

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff, I appreciate your answer, it contains many tricks like the evaluation IS NULL and the conversion in place to `int`. Just a question, you mention that the code will keep all visitors `(VIS01,VIS02,VIS03)` but I run it on a fiddle and only returned 2 visitors `(VIS01 and VIS02)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Manu . . . I left in the `WHERE` clause.  The answer is fixed and the explanation now correct.